# Make the table td flexible on small size

Tags: html, css

I need help making the td of a table flexible.

What I got going on is this: http://jsfiddle.net/j8GyV/23/

```
.card_new {
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888;
    border-top: 10px solid green;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding-: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.name_new {
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -70px;
}

.info_new {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: segoe ui;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#mainbox, .split_3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is exactly what I got going on in the jsfiddle, but when the width of the result window gets small enough for the table td's to be stacked on-top of eachother, I want the table td to start resizing(being flexible) itself to still fit in the result window, and not have the right side disappear behind the edge.

Comment: In the fiddle you provided, I can never get the right side to disappear behind "the edge"...?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lyJJj34.png Like that, you see how the a bit of the card has disappeared behind the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .card_new {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/j8GyV/25/

Comment: No joke, I thought of trying that but I thought it would never work. Thank you so much! Learn from mistakes! :D

Answer (score 0):

So I knew what you meant so I decided to add styling to `td` to make it wrap.

```
td {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

And it worked!
http://jsfiddle.net/j8GyV/30/